# How can I add a column in Google Spreadsheet matrix?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have two separate Google Spreadsheet documents, let's call them Tom and Jerry. They contain the same table but have different data in it. For example:

Tom:

```
SERIE            RATING
Friends          5
Suits            4
Ray Donavon      2
```

Jerry:

```
SERIE            RATING
Game of Thrones  5
Black Mirror     3
Breaking Bad     5
```

Now I like to combine them in a different Google Spreadsheet so I enter:

```
=QUERY(
    {
        QUERY(
            IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_TOM";"RANGE_DATA_NAME");"SELECT * WHERE Col1 <>''"
        );
        QUERY(
            IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_JERRY";"RANGE_DATA_NAME");"SELECT * WHERE Col1<>''"
        )
    };"SELECT *"
)
```

Now I have all the data:

```
Friends          5
Suits            4
Ray Donavon      2
Game of Thrones  5
Black Mirror     3
Breaking Bad     5
```

However what is lost in the query is that now I have no idea who rated what. So my preferred outcome would have been like this:

```
Tom    Friends          5
Tom    Suits            4
Tom    Ray Donavon      2
Jerry  Game of Thrones  5
Jerry  Black Mirror     3
Jerry  Breaking Bad     5
```

Now I don't want to add a useless column to the documents of Tom & Jerry containing simple the name copied in every row. There has to be another way so I can use it in a formula. So the question:

How can I add a column with the name in Google Spreadsheet matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I NOT dig for an answer when Tom and Jerry are involved?

Placing this in cell H1 of a sheet will cause column H to have the same values as column A, I as B, J as C AND has the added function of placing "Tom" (without the quotes) in column K:

```
={A1:C,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,"Tom"))}
```

So we change that a bit for the Importrange function and get:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_TOM", "sheet1!A1:C"),
   ARRAYFORMULA( 
    IF( 
      ISBLANK( 
          IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_TOM", "sheet1!A1:A")
      )
     ,,"Tom")
   )
 }
```

SO we should be able to use that for your formula to add Tom and Jerry to the imported ranges arrays and even simplify the formula a bit:

```
=QUERY(
  {
   {
    IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_TOM", "sheet1!A1:C"),
    ARRAYFORMULA(
     IF(
      ISBLANK(
       IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_TOM", "sheet1!A1:A")
      )
      ,,"Tom"
     )
    )
  };{
    IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_JERRY", "sheet1!A1:C"),
     ARRAYFORMULA(
      IF(
       ISBLANK(
        IMPORTRANGE("DOCUMENT_ID_JERRY", "sheet1!A1:A")
       )
      ,,"Jerry"
     )
    )
   }
 }
 , "Select * where Col2 <> ''"
)
```

Note that I am NOT using a named range to minimize the use of the various ranges but also because a named range does not grow.  It goes to the last row in the sheet when the range was created.

The use of commas and semicolons in the {} determines if the values are added to the end of the array or create a new column.  See the [help on Arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) for more.

Comment: Tom still wasn't able to catch Jerry this time. Thanks Karl for the efforts! Also somehow your formula gave me an error I needed to write it as follows: "={A1:C\ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A);;"Tom"))}"

Comment: Here is the unadulterated formula with a bit of the actual ID's removed.  It works in my test files: `=QUERY({{IMPORTRANGE("19d4zgcwqZItI8baAy8kk9suEN1bbV94I", "Form Responses 1!A1:C"), ARRAYFORMULA( IF( ISBLANK( IMPORTRANGE("19d4zgcRkrJ3xI8baAy8kk9suEN1bbV94I", "Form Responses 1!A1:A")),,"Tom"))};{IMPORTRANGE("19d4zgcRkrJ3aAy8kk9suEN1bbV94I", "Form Responses 1!A1:C"), ARRAYFORMULA( IF( ISBLANK( IMPORTRANGE("19d4zgcRkrJ3xAy8kk9suEN1bbV94I", "Form Responses 1!A1:A")),,"Jerry"))}}, "Select * where Col2 <> ''")`